# How to get/find the sum of all numbers starting with 1 and ending with N using Bash or similar

Tags: bash, sum, sequence, calculation, subtotal

How can you get/find the sum of all numbers starting with 1 and ending with N using Bash or similar? For example 1 to 50.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo $[ $(seq -s '+' 1 50) ]
1275
```

Will give the sum of all numbers from 1 to 50, using the `seq` command, a subshell (`$()`) and a calculation (`$[]`).